# Models of conic bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, conic-bundles

Let $S$ be a smooth projective variety over $\mathbb{C}$. A *conic bundle* over $S$ is a smooth projective variety $X$ together with a flat morphism $\pi:X \to S$ all of whose fibres are isomorphic to plane conics.

Let $Y$ be a smooth projective variety equipped with a morphism $\psi:Y \to S$ whose generic fibre is isomorphic to a smooth conic. Does $Y$ admit a conic bundle model?

More specifically, does there exist a conic bundle $\pi:X \to S$ and a birational map $\varphi: X \dashrightarrow Y$ such that $\pi = \psi \circ \varphi$?

**Remark:**
I'm happy with a weakening where there is a regular model where each fibre is a curve, not necessary a conic (i.e. singular fibres may have many irreducible components). But I definitely want my model to be flat over $S$!

Comment: No, there does not always exist such a conic bundle structure.  If you let yourself blow up $S$, then there will always exist a conic bundle structure.  If you start with a conic bundle $X'\to S'$ and then consider a contraction $S'\to S$, then for some strict resolution of singularities $Y\to X'$, the composition from $Y$ to $S$ will satisfy your hypotheses.  But typically there is no conic bundle structure over $S$ that pulls back over $S'$ to be $S'$-birational to $X'$.  The most well-studied example is the "quasi-map contraction" $S$ of the moduli space of stable maps $S'$.

Comment: Thanks Jason! Do you a reference/proof for why a conic bundle structure exists after possibly blowing-up S?

Comment: I've found reference: Theorem 1.13 in "V. G. Sarkisov - On conic bundle structures". Thanks!